# How to access ASP Core Web Api running in Docker using Postman

Tags: docker, api, asp.net-core, postman

I would like to make REST calls to my ASP Core Web Api running in Docker by using Postman. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyApp.API/MyApp.API.csproj", "MyApp.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp.API/MyApp.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApp.API"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.API.dll"]
```

Using Visual Studio 2019, I click on the Docker run button which builds the image and creates a container. However, Postman cannot access the API running in Docker. The error message is "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51005." Is there a port command that I should use? If so, where should I put it? Thanks.

Comment: can you run docker inspect [containerid] and find the ip address of the container.

Comment: After running docker inspect [containerId], I received this: "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
 "Ports": {
     "443/tcp": [
         {
             "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
             "HostPort": "11718"
         }
     ],
     "80/tcp": [
         {
             "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
             "HostPort": "11719"
         }
     ]   Then I tried https://localhost:11718  and 443 from Postman with no luck.

Comment: As far as I can see 11718 is your HTTPS Port and 11718 is your HTTP Port, you tried both?

Comment: After running docker ps, I get 0.0.0.0:[random port]/tcp. From Postman, I can access the container within the host using this: https ://localhost:[random port]/api/[and so on]. The problem now is that after every change to my code and after re-running docker build and publish, the random port number changes. This does not help in local testing because all of the external containers that call this central container must now have their references changed to the central container because of the change in ports. I need to be able to set a fixed port number. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add the container to a minikube cluster and use a k8s service . That will give you a static port

Comment: I have a similar problem where I request `GET http://localhost:49153/api/stocks/get`
but response `Error: socket hang up`.